# PHP generate random phrases from text

Tags: php, string

I am trying to build unique random phrases from text for detecting plagiarism. The idea is author will submit an article and then php will build phrases from text which will be used for plagiarism detection

Consider following sentence:

> This is a very long and boring article and this article is plagiarized.

Based upon the above text, system will determine how many phrases will be generated i.e. 20 words long article will have 3 phrases. Max generated phrase can be minimum two words long and maximum 3 words long. The returned output will be like this

- very long
- article is plagiarized

I wrote following code

```
$words = str_word_count($text, 1);
$total_phrases_required = count($words) /2;
//build phrases
```

I need hint how to complete rest of the part.

Comment: If you want to automatically create phrases you can search for you need a database with common words (like "a", "is", "and" ...) and filter those from the text. The remaining words will be the buzzwords to search for. This can be optimized, of course, to get little sentences, but this will require much more logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could break up text into two arrays of sentences  and then use a function like the [similar_text](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function to recursively check for similar strings.

Another idea, to find outright pauperism.  You could break down text into sentences again.  But then put into a database and run a query that selects count of index column and groups by sentence column.  If any results comes back greater than 1, you to have an exact match for that sentence.